# Joomla custom fields inside blog view

Tags: joomla, custom-fields

I've created custom fields for articles ánd for categories in joomla3.7.

(I am able to add the **article custom fields** into blog-item.php using `$this->item->jcfields[xxx]->value`

But how can I add the **category custom fields** into my template (into blog.php).

**Edit**

I need to add them by their ID. I do know how to override the template. I don't know how to add the custom fields used in the category in blog.php (in my template).

Answer (score 0):

You can do an override coping  `components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php` into your template folder `templates/your template/html/com_content/category` and make changes on it

Comment: I know how to override the files. I want to be able to add specific custom field used in the category in my template overrides.